# Is the liquid in this question water? How can one know for sure?

Tags: heat, temperature

I have been studying and there is a question in my book asking:

> A faulty thermometer reads freezing and boiling point of a liquid as -5°C and 95°C respectively on the Celsius scale. What is the correct value of temperature when it reads 60°C on the faulty thermometer?
>
> (a) 60°C (b) 65°C (c) 64°C (d) 62°C

The solution on back of the textbook is as follows:

> (b) 65°C

> For all temperature scales,
>
> (X - LFP)/(UFP - LFP) = constant
>
> where LFP is Lower fixed point, and UFP is Upper fixed point
>
> [X - (-5)]/[95 - (-5)] = (C - 0)/(100 - 0)
>
> => (60 + 5)/(95 + 5) = C/100
>
> => C = 65°C

In this, I do not understand from where the `C - 0` and `100 - 0` came in step 2

EDIT: Fixed typo from -95°C to 95°C

Comment: It seems it is not only a faulty termometer, but also faulty assignement. there should be -5  deg C and +95  deg C, with the correction of adding +5 deg C, probably due accidental shifting of the scale bar. Therefore 60->65, as the liquid is obviously  water. C-0 and 100-0 comes from mapping function  -5..+95 to 0..100.

Comment: I think you're getting "the lamest title of the day" prize... but the day's still young here ;)

Comment: Please change the title of question to reflect what is being asked in the body of the post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains typos that should be fixed (or if the textbook problem had the typo, include the source). In fact, always include the source if you cite something.

Comment: @Poutnik I'm sorry, i accidently wrote -95 instead of 95 degrees.

Comment: @Karsten can you please point out the typos? I can't find them. If you mean the formula, I've double checked it and that's exactly what the textbook said

Comment: Also, if not chemistry stack exchange, which site can i post this question to?

Comment: @InfoDaneMent You fixed the typo. Did your version of the question state that the sample is water? Could you add which textbook you found this in? You can find similar problems and answers [here](https://www.sarthaks.com/2029835/faulty-thermometer-freezing-point-boiling-water-respectively-correct-value-temperatu), [here](https://www.quora.com/A-faulty-thermometer-reads-5-degree-Celsius-in-melting-ice-and-99-degree-Celsius-in-steam-What-will-be-the-correct-temperature-in-Fahrenheit-when-this-faulty-thermometer-reads-52-degree-Celsius), and [there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UO0VjZR7WGQ).

Comment: @Karsten but how can it be assumed that the correct readings are 100 and 0 degree Celsius?

Comment: @Karsten no, it isn't written in the question anywhere that the liquid is water.

Comment: @InfoDaneMent please edit the question to state    where the problem set comes from.

Comment: @Karsten you mean the textbook name and version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a faulty question and data as pointed out by Poutnik. Instead of "a" liquid, it should be water. Don't use plug and chug formulae. When it is known that the liquid is water, recognize the fact that the freezing point is -5 °C, and the +95 °C for the boiling point on this thermometer. This statement is to show that the systematic error is constant in this temperature range. What do you have to do to make -5 °C to 0 °C and +95 °C to 100 °C? Add +5 °C. Make this correction with this understanding in observed 60 °C and you get the textbook answer.

Comment: The question is nonsense, Chemically to assume a liquid is water is foolish, dangerous, and potentially fatal. A typo is the responsibility of the typist not the reader. The scale is inverted so a 60 degree reading is colder than the FP T; no listed answer can be correct.  All that is needed to fix the question is one defined Kelvin temperature measurement  [the BP of water was -95 at ~600Torr. =368 K or the ice point 273K less variable] That with absolute zero  defines the absolute scale, a translation defines the new scale. The student who figures it out learns something.

Comment: @jimchmst Other cases than constant offset are highly improbable, so take it as educated guess.

Comment: But the question does not mention that the liquid is water

Comment: @InfoDaneMent, That is why we said that it was a poorly designed question by the question author (not you!).